# Xcode not detecting iPhone

Tags: iphone

i am using XCode 4.1, when i open an old project it is showing the iPhone device, but it is not detecting the iphone device on a new project.

Thanks

Comment: Does the iPhone device have the right software version? For example, is your deployment target for the new project something like iOS 5 but the device has iOS 4.2 installed?

Answer (score 10):

You probably need to go into organizer... devices.. from the Window Menu I believe