# Xcode can't detect iPhone device with iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I have updated my iPhone firmware to 5.1. I notice now that Xcode 4.2 doesn't recognize the device. Do I need to upgrade Xcode or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xcode 4.3 is able to run app on devices running iOS 5.1

You need to upgrade you current version..(Note :Xcode 4.3 and above are only available for Mac OSX Lion)

Comment: We can use ios5.1 device with xcode 4.2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611596/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-and-retina-in-ipad-3/9728951#9728951

Comment: After doing above fix. Also check this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747547/xcode-not-detecting-iphone/8747629#comment13428580_8747629

Comment: is it new thing in Xcode? I remember using Xcode 3 with iPhone 4S, though I couldn't debbug on device with higher iOS than SDK within Xcode...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Xcode 4.2 and the version of the SDK bundled with it do not support the latest version of iOS. Upgrade to Xcode 4.3.1. To do this, you will need to upgrade to OS X 10.7 Lion if you have not already done so.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't upgrade to Xcode 4.3 for some reason, such as running Snow Leopard, you can make Xcode 4.2 work with 5.1 devices. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649313/is-there-a-way-to-downgrade-from-ios-5-1-to-ios-5-0/9649396#9649396).

Comment: that answer is about to get closed along with the question. I've copied my notes here http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2012/03/install-ios-51-on-snow-leopard-and.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to update your XCode Version.

Xcode 4.3.1 has been launched with the new iOS 5.1.

You can find how to download it there :

[Apple Developer Website (iOS & XCode)](https://developer.apple.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Shubhank's answer (and everyone else), remember that Apple's app store is where the download is. So it will magically put itself somewhere (the Developer dir) without overwriting Xcode.

You have to find it and replace your shortcuts to launch 4.3 instead of 4.2. There aren't any hints, or "open extracted folder" or anything. In case you wonder why you open Xcode and it still doesn't find it. You go into the App Store and notice it says "Installed", but never is there a link to figure out where, so you have to dig and hope, comparing creation times in the files.

(After you do this, it will offer to remove 4.2)

If anyone had a smoother time, please post how!